# How to set focus on a particular row in a datagrid/gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagrid

I have a datagrid/gridview. I'm populating the grid with 10 rows initially. On a button click every time,I'm keeping on adding 10 rows to the datagrid/gridview. Now I want to set the focus to the last row every time the grid is populated. I can get the index of that row,but I can't set focus to that particular row.

Do anyone of you have any idea how to do it in C#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;

dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Friend,I'm setting the focus in that button's click event.And I can't find any property for gridview as 'Row' and'.Selected'.Please tell me how can I get them..

Comment: Thanks.I tried your code but it's giving error as "GridviewRow doesn't contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow could be found".Am I missing any directive or assembly reference?

Answer (score 10):

For WinForms DataGridView:

```
myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows[theRowIndex].Cells[0];
```

For WebForms GridView, use the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx) property

```
myGridView.SelectedIndex = theRowIndex;
```

Comment: @Sukanya There is for [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx). Are you working with the WebForm GridView? If yes, please mark this in your question.

Comment: Friend,I'm using .net 4.0.I'm creating web form.I'm getting only 2 asp grid and they are DataGrid and Gridview.For both these grids,I'm not getting .CurrentCell property.Is anything wrong from my side?And second point is I've been able to set the point to a particular rowindex using 'SelectedIndex' but my problem is I've not been able to focus to that particular row..

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
DataGridViewRow rowToSelect = this.dgvJobList.CurrentRow;

rowToSelect.Selected = true;



rowToSelect.Cells[0].Selected = true;

this.dgvJobList.CurrentCell = rowToSelect.Cells[0];

this.dgvJobList.BeginEdit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's work for me

```
   public static void ItemSetFocus(DataGrid Dg, int SelIndex)
    {
        if (Dg.Items.Count >= 1 && SelIndex < Dg.Items.Count)
        {
           Dg.ScrollIntoView(Dg.Items.GetItemAt(SelIndex));
           Dg.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single;
           Dg.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
           Dg.SelectedIndex = SelIndex;
           DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelIndex);
                row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has been a god send.  I am using VB in Visual Studio 2017 and just needed to go to the bottom of a DATAGRID to allow user to input data.  By studying these answers I came up with this solution and thought others might find it useful.

```
Private Sub AddBUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles 
AddBUTTON.Click
        ' Go to bottom to allow user to add item in last row
        DataGrid.Focus()
        DataGrid.UnselectAll()
        DataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0
        DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid.SelectedItem)
        Dim endofitems As Integer = DataGrid.Items.Count         
        DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(endofitems - 1))
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a button which add new row to `datagridView1` and activate newly added row's second cell C# Windows Form Application.

```cs
int rowIndex = datagridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
datagridView1.CurrentCell = datagridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1];
datagridView1.BeginEdit(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I'm works well with below script snippet in Extjs 4.2.0.

```
//currentIndex is the index of grid row
var rowElement = this.getView().getRecord(currentIndex);
this.getView().focusRow(rowElement);
```