# Selecting and Focusing a Datagrid based on a variable

Tags: c#, focus, wpfdatagrid

I want to keep this short and sweet. I can't figure out how to set focus and go to a certain row based on a user input, either like TextBox or a ComboBox. I keep trying different ways to try and write it but with no success. I have a combobox that when they insert a input like the id of 1567, I want the datagrid to find the row that has the variable id of 1567. I know this has had to be done before since it seems like something people would really use in a application.

To clarify more

I have this table

```
ID FirstName LastName Comments
123 Kyle        Bro     Comments???
145 Zach        Gred    Something??
178 Derrick     Davidson More??
```

I want to select the row where the ID field equals 145, not the actual row number which would be 1. I am pulling the data from a database, so I want to focus based on a cell not the row ID.

Thanks to D_Learning I got it to select with code

```
try
{
     if(dataGrid2.SelectedItem == null)
     {
         dataGrid2.SelectedItem = dataGrid2.Items.GetItemAt(0);
     }
     var selectedObj = dataGrid2.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(a => a[0].ToString() == IDComboBox.Text);
     if (selectedObj != null)
     {
          dataGrid2.SelectedItem = selectedObj;
          dataGrid2.ScrollIntoView(selectedObj);
          dataGrid2.Focus();
     }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException  e)
{

}
```

My issues have been resolved with adding the dataGrid2.SelectedItem = dataGrid2.Items.GetItemAt(0); and checking for null.

Comment: actually this is short and sweet... `This is actually quite simple and if you do a google search you will find many examples` here is a `Free-B` for ya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635731/how-to-set-focus-on-a-particular-row-in-a-datagrid-gridview

Comment: @MethodMan this isn't what I am looking for. I am assuming I would need a linq statement.

Comment: that link provides many ways of using Linq you just have to know how to use it against the TextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for as below:

```
var selectedObj = dgGrid.Items.Cast<YourClass>().First(a=> a.ID = txtFilter.Text);
if(selectedObj != null)
    dgGrid.SelectedItem =  selectedObj;
```

Please let me know if above doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ok that part works, now I have a new issue that I added above.

Comment: As far as I think the error you are getting might be due to dataGrid2.ScrollIntoView(selectedObj); can you check if this is the case. Also if you can copy the exact error that is appearing perhaps it might be another simple solution.

Comment: No its not a error with the dataGrid2.ScrollIntoView(selectedObj). It has something to do when there is nothing already selected it won't select a row.

Comment: I am not sure why or what is the exact cause of the Error but you can put a check i.e. IF condition of the datagrid selected item before assigning the selectedObj and make sure that if the previously selected Item is null then make 0 Index of Datagrid as selected.

Comment: Thank you that suggestion worked. I posted the full example code for all future people needing help with this.