# C# DataGridView set focus on a row instead of cell when hit TAB

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabs, focus

I have a winforms datagridview, when I hit TAB, the focus rectangle (dotted rectangle) sets to a cell and starts moving from cell to cell as I keep hitting the button, instead I want the rectangle to be set to the entire row not just the cell and once I start hitting TAB it should move from **row to row**.

I have tried setting the `selctionmode` to `fullrowselect` but still the focus sets for cell. 
[image][image]

Can you please suggest me any workaround to achieve the objective here. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on a particular row in a datagrid/gridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635731/how-to-set-focus-on-a-particular-row-in-a-datagrid-gridview)

Comment: @S.Petrosov In the shared link it shows how to set the selection, but I need to set the focus here, basically I'm looking for a way where I can get the focus set on the entire row once I hit TAB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use with `SelectionMode` as `FullRowSelect` the `datagridview`s `KeyDown event` such as

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        int activeRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if ((activeRow + 1) < dataGridView1.RowCount)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[activeRow+1].Cells[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Also for selection rectangle you can add in the `CellPainting` event the folowing code

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            && e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All& ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 0))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Width -= 2;
                rect.Height -= 2;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution is good, it helps me moving from row to row after every TAB hit, but again as I said the dotted rectangle/ focus rectangle is shown only for a particular cell, in my case as per the screenshots, it is 'last name' column. I wish I could get it for entire row.

Comment: Thanks @Moutlou Nteli Chasan Moustafa, I tried it but it is not giving what I'm expecting. It is giving a black colored border around the cell, instead of the dotted rectangle. Also, it is not doing it for the entire row. It is happening for the cell.

Comment: Actually it is dotted rectangle around cell, you can change pen color to white to see it. If you want to have a dashed border around row select, you can use the same login at `dataGridView1_RowPostPaint` event. @pradeeppradyumna

Comment: @Berkay if you don't mind, can you please share a code sample for that. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.,

Using Tab:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Using Mouseclick:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
```

Comment: SelectionMode = FullRowSelect is working me, try this

Comment: Um tried, not working for me as it just sets the selection and not the focus, by focus I mean the dotted rectangle that appears when you hit TAB

Comment: we can remove focus completely but for complete row focus...i'm checking and i'll update you if i get the solution