# Why load in DataGridView does not exist shows active in row header

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Why load in DataGridView does not exist shows active in row header vb.net?

If I click the mouse, it appears active in the row header of the datagridview. It should first load the form, then the row header datagridview appears immediately without clicking on the mouse. Is there something wrong with my datagridview?.

[image: no active rowheader]

[image: active rowheader]

update samplegrid via google drive
Here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cLQC-SsxyrqiAjfQOI7fYJyr68zGSOsG/view?usp=share_link)!

Comment: Do you want it to select the first row when the form loads?

Comment: @CoolCoder123 , sorry I replied late, yes I want to select the first row when the form loads

Answer (score 0):

You can focus the first row like this:

```
myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0)
```

Take from here [How to set focus on a particular row in a datagrid/gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635731/how-to-set-focus-on-a-particular-row-in-a-datagrid-gridview)

Comment: thanks for your answer , but I have an error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: Your grid appears to customized or something it might be something to do with that.

Comment: or I try sharing the sample project related to the problem if you don't mind

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cLQC-SsxyrqiAjfQOI7fYJyr68zGSOsG/view?usp=share_link) , I updated the sample grid which does not show the active row icon

Answer (score 0):

```
private shadows sub bufferToUp(dgv as datagridview, setting as boolean) 
  Dim dgvType=dgv.GetType
  Dim proInfo as propertyinfo=dgvtype.getProperty("DoubleBuffered",BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.nonPublic)
  proInfo.SetValue(dgv,setting,nothing)
End sub
```

'In load form paste the

```
bufferToUp(dgv,True)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but thanks your answer , i tried your code no active effect in first line datagridview